# Auto updating Windows 10 USB

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

Once in a while I need to do a fresh Windows install which I do from a usb. I always use the official [Windows installation media tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) which works perfectly. However I always need to spend some time setting it up with the latest version of windows before I use it. Is there any way I can leave it plugged into a computer/server and have it automatically download the latest install media so that it's ready whenever I need it?

Comment: I'd look at better ways of managing your machine, to avoid having to clean install so frequently. You only need clean installs if you're destruct-testing or running 'dangerous' content… both of which would be far safer & faster to achieve in a VM with snapshots.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not necessarily talking about my own computer. I help friends and family sometimes with their computers which sometimes require a fresh install. It's not so frequent, but it does happen enough to warrant my question.

Comment: Ah, OK, yes. I gave up doing that a long time ago. I kind of got sick of "Why is my computer slow?" "Well, that'll be the ransomware fighting with the three botnets" ;))

Answer (score 1):

It is the newest version at the time that version comes out. Then it gets behind until the next new version comes out (every 6 to 12 months). So it is not really "always current"

It seems as easy to download the new version when you need it.  I assume you are not reinstalling Windows every 6 months. Repair Install can fix you up in between times.

I do not think constantly download the newest ISO will save you much is there would be a lot of duplication (same version for a while).

I suggest not trying to constantly download (no real value).

I suggest downloading it when you really need it as that should save downloading time.

You might also look up Microsoft Update Enablement as they are looking at ways to update peoples systems while keeping them up to date at all times.

[Update Enablement](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/it-tools-to-support-windows-10-version-21h1/ba-p/2365103)

I once got a jump on V1703 (long time ago) by downloading the Insider Version, updating and leaving the program on this machine. That is because the MCL ISO was the old version and would not give me anything.

I do still have a different Insider machine, by the way.

Comment: I think there's a way to add the updates to the installation media. Regardless, windows releases new versions more often than that.
I'm not looking to duplicate the download, but if there is a new version to automatically download it so that I have it ready to go.

Comment: The MCL link is only as new as the newest version. This article (https://www.windowslatest.com/2021/05/19/windows-10-may-2021-update-21h1-iso-images/) and others suggests it is not updated outside of the updates it does when you install it.

Comment: You might also look up Microsoft Update Enablement which is a way of pre-supplying updates to be release on your system at a specific point of time that Microsoft determines. Having your own download runs a bit counter to that process.